# Where is the apache pid file on Gentoo?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, process, gentoo, pid

I need it to configure Monit, but the path in the sample config file is `/usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid` and it's not there. It's also not anywhere in `/etc` (at least not with that name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! It's in:

`/var/run/apache2.pid`

Comment: You should accept your own answer -- this gives you points (and a badge) and lets the rest of the community know you're no longer looking for an answer.

Comment: Note that this also seems to be true for Apache 2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/run/apache.pid`, from memory.